# Swift 3: How to let a constant according to different case?

Tags: swift

```
    let action = { () -> Action in
        if fromView == self.defaultView {
            return Action.push
        } else if toView == self.defaultView {
            return Action.pop
        } else {
            return Action.swap
        }
    }()
```

I want to let a constant according to different case.

Is this the right way?
(It's works fine, I just want to find a more elegant way. ）

Comment: It depends on the context. If the value you're checking against is an enum, for instance, you might use the line let action : Action , followed by a switch statement. If the code you've listed is working as intended, it's fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Is this the right way*"? Does it compile? (if so, what are you actually asking about?) Is `action` a property or a local variable?

Comment: @Hamish Yes, it's works fine. I just want to find a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this inside a method (and your `action` variable is not a property), you don't need the closure, you can write :

```
let action: Action
if fromView == self.defaultView {
    action = .push
} else if toView == self.defaultView {
    action = .pop
} else {
    action = .swap
}
```

If your if/else handles all the cases, the compiler will not complain that the `action` variable is used uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Please find piece of code below. If you want to use it as let constant.

```
let action: Action {
  get {
    switch self.defaultView {
       case fromView:
          return Action.push
       case toView:
          return Action.pop
      default:
        return Action.swap
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Computed properties have to be declared using `var`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right syntax for populating a constant using your conditions

```
let action = { () -> Action in
    switch self.defaultView {
    case self.fromView: return .push
    case self.toView: return .pop
    default: return .swap
    }
}()
```

Full example

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let fromView = UIView()
    let defaultView = UIView()
    let toView = UIView()

    func foo() {
        let action = { () -> Action in
            switch self.defaultView {
            case self.fromView: return .push
            case self.toView: return .pop
            default: return .swap
            }
        }()
    }
}

enum Action {
    case push, pop, swap
}
```

Comment: The closure is not necessary, as presented by @deadbeef.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yes but it's a clean solution if you want to wrap the logic  that does populate the constant.